# Trying to create React component with textarea that auto expands and shrinks based on content height (with Sandbox)

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, styled-components, react-hooks

I'm trying to build this `TextArea` component that uses React hook and `styled-components`.

Everything goes well when my `textarea` is gaining new lines. The expand feature is working as expected.

What I'm doing, basically, is:

- Using `textAreaRef`- `useRef()` to store a ref to the `textarea` element
- Using `lastScrollHeight`- `useRef()` to store the last `ScrollHeight`
- Using `idealHeight`- `useRef()` to store the ideal height for the `textarea`

I calculate the `idealHeight` based on the value of the `lastScrollHeight` that has been stored on the previous render. Then I compare with the current value of `textAreaRef.current.scrollHeight` and I calculate the `delta`.

Then I calculate the `idealHeight.current = idealHeight.current + delta` and send it as `props` to my styled-component `TextAreaInput` to set the `height`.

**THE PROBLEM**

`scrollHeight` increases when new lines are added and returns a positive `delta`. But `scrollHeight` doesn't decrease when lines are removed. So `delta` comes back zero.

I need a way to measure the height of the text content inside of the `textarea`. I saw some questions here on SO that recommended to do this by setting `height` of the element to a very small value before asking for the `scrollHeight`.

Indeed, that gives me the negative `deltas` that I want, but that just stops any expanding or shrinking, and I get a scroll bar instead. See that by toggling the commented line `textAreaRef.current.style.height = "2px";`. Some how the component gets stuck on `height='2px'`. I don't know.

[Code SandBox with working example](https://codesandbox.io/s/4xqp39nqx) (mind the console logs)

Any ideas what's going wrong?

**TextArea.js**

```
import React, { useRef } from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";

const TextAreaInput = styled.textarea`
  height: ${props => props.idealHeight || "152px"};
  min-height: 32px;
  max-height: 320px;
  line-height: 21px;
  width: 100%;
  resize: vertical;
  box-sizing: border-box;

  border: 1px solid rgb(217, 217, 217);
  padding: 4px 11px;
  text-size-adjust: 100%;
`;

function TextArea(props) {
  const idealHeight = useRef(32);
  const lastScrollHeight = useRef(30);
  const textAreaRef = useRef(null);

  console.log("ANOTHER RENDER...");

  if (textAreaRef.current !== null && textAreaRef.current !== undefined) {
    const scrollHeight = textAreaRef.current.scrollHeight;

    // THIS NEXT LINE MAKES THE DELTA CALCULATION CORRECT ON 'SHRINKING'
    // BUT STOPS THE RESIZING

    // textAreaRef.current.style.height = "2px";

    const delta = scrollHeight - lastScrollHeight.current;
    console.log("Delta is: " + delta);

    console.log("Last ScrollHeight: " + lastScrollHeight.current);
    lastScrollHeight.current = scrollHeight;

    console.log("Current ScrollHeight: " + lastScrollHeight.current);

    idealHeight.current = idealHeight.current + delta;

    console.log("IdealHeight :" + idealHeight.current);
  }

  return (
    <TextAreaInput
      placeholder={props.placeholder}
      value={props.value}
      onChange={e => props.setValue(e.target.value)}
      ref={textAreaRef}
      idealHeight={idealHeight.current + "px"}
    />
  );
}

export default TextArea;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just came up with a solution:

In order to get the content `height` inside the `textarea`, first we need to set its `height` property to `0px` and then get its `scrollHeight`.

But when you do this, you end up creating an inline style with `height=0px`, and that gets the highest precedence of CSS rules, so you need to unset it with:

`textAreaRef.current.removeAttribute('style');`

That is needed because all my CSS is being applied by styled-components, that uses the `<style>` html tag inside `<head>`, which has lower precedence than inline CSS.

So the final and working code is:

**TextArea.js**

```
function TextArea(props) {

  const idealHeight = useRef(32);
  const lastScrollHeight = useRef(30);
  const textAreaRef = useRef(null);

  if (textAreaRef.current != null && textAreaRef.current != undefined) {

    textAreaRef.current.style.height = '0px'; // This creates an inline style

    let scrollHeight = textAreaRef.current.scrollHeight;

    const style = window.getComputedStyle(textAreaRef.current);

    textAreaRef.current.removeAttribute('style'); // The inline style must be removed

    let delta = scrollHeight-lastScrollHeight.current;

    lastScrollHeight.current = scrollHeight;

    idealHeight.current = idealHeight.current + delta;

  }

  return(
    <TextAreaInput
      placeholder={props.placeholder}
      value={props.value}
      onChange={props.onChange}
      ref={textAreaRef}
      idealHeight={idealHeight.current + 'px'}
    />
  );

}
```